# Set default max_lo for NHibernate HiLo generator?

Tags: nhibernate

Is there any way to set a default value for max_lo that will take effect for all mapped entities? All of my entities are currently mapped via Xml. I know the default is 32678, but I would like to reduce this to 1000.

I've had a look through the NH configuration xsd and I can't see any settings in there. I think that you should be able to achieve this ok if you are mapping by code, but I am currently using Xml and don't fancy changing across.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also override the value on SessionFactory generation, which is only done once:

```
private void InitSessionFactory()
{
     var cfg = new Configuration().Configure();
     foreach (var cm in cfg.ClassMappings) {
           if (cm.Identifier.IsSimpleValue) {
               var simpleVal = cm.Identifier as SimpleValue;
               if (simpleVal.IdentifierGeneratorStrategy == "hilo"){
                    simpleVal.IdentifierGeneratorProperties["max_lo"] = "1000";
               }
           }
     }
     sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
 }
```

this NH2 code so for NH3 there might be some differences

Answer (score 0):

No way to configure default/global from hbm. `Int16.MaxValue` is simply hardcoded in NHibernate (as of 3.2). `TableHiLoGenerator` [source](http://www.google.com/codesearch#5Cej6qWZ2UY/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/Id/TableHiLoGenerator.cs&q=TableHiLoGenerator%20lang%3a%5Ec#%24&type=cs):

```
public override void Configure(IType type, ...)
{
    ...
    maxLo = PropertiesHelper.GetInt64(MaxLo, parms, Int16.MaxValue);
    ...
}
```

I guess you can open feature request [here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be possible to do this by extending the NH hilo generator as per http://daniel.wertheim.se/2011/03/08/nhibernate-custom-id-generator/